# How can I control font of the Finder's sidebar?

Tags: finder, catalina, font, 4k, sidebar

In the finder, there is a sidebar that includes things like Favorites for easy access.  On my laptop running Catalina, the font size is much larger than I desire on my 4K screen for the sidebar.

Where can I control the font size used by the sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidebar text size cannot be adjusted independently. However, this setting:

```
  System Preferences > General > Sidebar Icon Size
```

changes the size of the Sidebar icons and text names.